# Flask SQLite3 building hyperlink to view specific row data

Tags: python, templates, sqlite, flask, jinja2

Trying to build a valid link that will go to a separate templated page for viewing a single post. Currently only lists all posts from the database. Getting a 500 error regardless when I use the "view_entry" in the link. Am I not pulling the "ID" properly so it isn't actually seeing that field value?

List Template - show_entries.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <ul class=entries>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('view_entry', id = entry.id) }}"><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2></a>{{ entry.text|safe }}
  {% else %}
    <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

show_entries / new_entry code

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select id, title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

# View specific entry
@app.route('/view_entry/<id>')
def view_entry(id):
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries where "id" = id')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('view_entry.html', entries=entries)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the app in debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you pass to the database is invalid. You are querying for any records where the `id` field is equal to the string `'id'`. Instead you want to query where the field is equal to the value passed to the view.

The correct way to do this is by passing the value in as a parameter.

```
cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries where id = ?', (id,))
```

After executing the cursor you'll want to fetch the first record, not all of them.

```
entries = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: made the changes with no affect. Did some isolated testing with the show_entries method on the template. Using entry.id instead of entry.title , gives me nothing. Yet when I pull it directly with sqlite3 in terminal it's there properly. Am I restricted from pulling and using/displaying the row ID possibly with sqlite3.

Comment: forgot to do a restart on the server side. It's building the link properly now. Wonderful answer and execution.